# Is there a way we can remove any characters within the " ", in the CSV file using python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file. It's huge and trying to manually edit it will take too long. I have some commas between " " which I want to remove. For example:

```
Symbol,name,is_etf,exchange
"A","Agilent Technologies, Inc.","null","NYSE"
"AA","Alcoa Corporation","null","NYSE"
"AAC","AAC Holdings, Inc.","null","NYSE"
```

As you can see in the in second line, it has a comma inside `"Agilent Technologies, Inc."`. I don't want to remove other commas, just the comma inside the double quotes.

How can we remove that?

Comment: Question is: why? The name must be written like that, why remove?

Comment: Because all I need is a symbol from this file and I'm removing " too, so when I do it will give me error due to multiple commas.

Comment: You can use regex and replace `,\s` with `\s`

Comment: Why are you removing `"`? You're trying to remove the `,` inside the `"`, because when you remove the `"` then the comma will mess up the data? **That's exactly why there are `"` in the first place,** to allow commas without messing up the data structure. So, why are you removing the quotes?

Comment: " are there exactly for the point, to differentiate commas commas as separators of fields and commas as normal characters. You are then doing it wrong. The question is: what do you want at the end? Give an example of from the sample dataset provided.

Comment: You have a `csv` module in the standard library, with a correctly working CSV parser. Stop trying to tinker with this perfectly well formatted data and use this proper tool.

Comment: I'm removing the quotes only after if I know there's a way to remove the comma btn the ". So there's not a way to remove , btn them right?

Comment: Again, forget about it and use the `csv` module. And if you are actually using Pandas, why would you need to do any such thing while you can just import the CSV properly?

Comment: Aight mates, thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: See http://xyproblem.info… What you'd have to do is parse the CSV using a proper CSV parser, remove the comma _from the data_, then write the data back to CSV using a proper CSV writer. But… why would you do anything like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `csv` from the standard library should work just fine.

```py
import csv

def remove_commas(in_file: str, out_file: str):
    with open(in_file, "r") as fi:
        with open(out_file, "w") as fo:
            reader = csv.reader(fi)
            writer = csv.writer(fo)
            for row in reader:
                writer.writerow([cell.replace(",", "") for cell in row])
```

Once you use that you might not have a need for removing commas anyway, but that's your business :)

Comment: FYI, you can combine the two `with` statements into one (`with a as b, c as d:`).

Answer (score 2):

The [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78040762/2429666) suggestion  of user2583328 is much better, but if you want to write your own implementation, consider something like:

```
data='''Symbol,name,is_etf,exchange
"A","Agilent Technologies, Inc.","null","NYSE"
"AA","Alcoa Corporation","null","NYSE"
"AAC","AAC Holdings, Inc.","null","NYSE"'''

print(data)
for line in data.split('\n'):
    # get all quoted words in 'line' by splitting and filtering on odd indices
    words = [value for index,value in enumerate(line.split('"')) if index%2==1]
    for word in words:
        print(word.replace(',', ''), ' | ', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: This is not a safe solution because some fields might contain double quotes. It works on the examples given, but it's hard to be sure it'll work on the whole huge file OP has. It's always best to stick with a real CSV parser that handles all the corner cases we might not think of.